# How to put data in already existing table on jsp page from ResultSet object?

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, oracle-adf

Hey I am new at using oracle jdeveloper 12c and i want to put data into web page from database progarmatically.

I created a jsp page having a button and a table (by drag and drop ) and have data in `ResultSet` object from database. i used `ResultSetDatModel` to put data from `ResultSet` to my table but when i press the button all things work properly in the button action except for data transferring to table  and table shows empty on web page.

Please help me i put my java code and output screen shot below. Thank you

```
package view;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.faces.model.ResultSetDataModel;

import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.data.RichTable;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.input.RichInputText;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.output.RichOutputLabel;
import oracle.adf.view.rich.context.AdfFacesContext;

public class Method {
    private RichInputText txtbox;
    private RichOutputLabel lbl;
    private RichOutputLabel lbl2;
    private RichTable table;

    public Method() {
    }

    public String textChange() {

        AdfFacesContext adf = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        adf.addPartialTarget(table);
        try{
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
                    Connection con =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@Jaffer:1521:XE", "HR","hr");
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rslt = stmt.executeQuery("select JOB_ID from         EMPLOYEES where LAST_NAME='King' AND EMAIL='SKING'");
                    rslt.next();
                    String str =rslt.getString(1).toString();
                    rslt = stmt.executeQuery("select * from JOBS where     JOB_ID='"+str+"'");
                    rslt.next();    
                    ResultSetDataModel dataModel=new ResultSetDataModel();
                    dataModel.setWrappedData(rslt);
                    table.setValue(dataModel);
                    //txtbox.setValue(rslt.getString(1).toString());
                }catch (Exception e){
                }
        return null;
    }

    public void setTxtbox(RichInputText txtbox) {
        this.txtbox = txtbox;
    }

    public RichInputText getTxtbox() {
        return txtbox;
    }

    public void setLbl(RichOutputLabel lbl) {
        this.lbl = lbl;
    }

    public RichOutputLabel getLbl() {
        return lbl;
    }

    public void setLbl2(RichOutputLabel lbl2) {
        this.lbl2 = lbl2;
    }

    public RichOutputLabel getLbl2() {
        return lbl2;
    }

    public void setTable(RichTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public RichTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hprOl.png)

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier for you to use ADF binding and ADF Business Components to get your DB data into an ADF Faces Table.
Here is a basic tutorial:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_rich_app_alta/tut_rich_app_alta_1.html

If you don't want to use the ADF Binding and ADF BC layers, then your managed bean needs to create a getter that returns a collection and then you can bind your ADF Faces table to that collection.
This is something you can see in the ADF Faces components demo code:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/documentation/adf-faces-rc-demo-083799.html

Comment: But i think ADF binding and Business Components not allows customization  and according to my condition i have to read data from two different tables that is not possible by joins also that's why i choose to code button action by myself  but i struck to put data into table from ResultSet object.

Comment: You can take your java class that merges the data from the two tables and expose it as a data control that you can bind to the table. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53569_01/tutorials/tut_bean_dc/tut_bean_dc.html

Answer (score -1):

You are looking at the problem from a wrong perspective: using JDBC to fill in an af:table.
What you need to remember is that ADF is a FULL STACK development framework, so you need to build the entire using ADF technologies.

So, instead of using JDBC, you should use ADF Business Components where you can build a View Object based on an SQL query. There are a lot of tutorials on this.

You will be wasting your time if you will want to use just the ADF Rich Faces layer, without ADF Bindings or ADF Business Components. ADF layers are tightly coupled.